# Blurry Image On iphone Jquery Mobile

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I am developing an events page using jquery mobile.   I have a stylish way of showing the date.  It currently works flawlessly on my desktop, yet when I view it on my iphone 3gs, I get a blurry Image.  The text seems as though it is duplicated on itself just slightly to look like this:   help please.

[image: Screenshot]

link to the page : [here](http://www.users.muohio.edu/vicarijd/Events.php)

Here is the css:

```
    .caldate2 { background: url(http://www.fsb.muohio.edu/fsb/templates/images/calpage-red.gif) no-repeat; 
           width:38px; 
           height:38px; 
           text-align:center;  
           margin-right:8px; 
           float: left; }
.caldate2 .day { 
    color: #fff; 
      margin-top:4px; }
.month {  text-transform:uppercase; 
         color:#d5b549; 
         font-size:9px; }
```

and the Markup:

```
<body>
  <div data-role="page" data-theme="a">
    <div data-role="header">
      <a data-rel="back" data-icon="back" data-direction="reverse">Back</a>

      <h1>Events</h1><a href="http://www.fsb.muohio.edu/" data-icon="home">Home</a>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">
      <ul data-role="listview" data-dividertheme="a" data-inset="true">
        <li data-role="list-divider">Divider</li>

        <li>
          <div class="caldate2">
            <div class="day">
              28
            </div>

            <div class="month">
              MAR
            </div>
          </div><a href="#">This is a test</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div><!-- /page -->
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mumis,

looking into it, it would appear the class:

```
.ui-btn-up-a {
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #EEEEEE;
}
```

is causing an extra "#EEE" text-shadow on the text.

Try removing that from the fsb.min.css file!

Oh and btw,
I'm from around SWOhio area (noticed the MUOhio)

Comment: That did it!  Miami Ohio is where its at!

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help!
Don't forget to make this the accepted answer to help others find this question relevant.

Comment: Hehe I've been looking for a polite way to say that. +1